# Plotting a floor function with endpoints?

Tags: plotting

Would someone mind showing me how to plot a floor function with the appropriate endpoints?  I tried Google, but the best I could find was something posted from 2004 that no longer appears to work.

Sorry if this is overly basic, I've only got a couple of weeks of experience with Mathematica and no one to work with on it.

Edit:  I'm looking to create a graph similar to the one shown on the [wiki page for floor/ceiling functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).  I'm not too concerned with the frame or the tick marks.

Comment: You just need to add `Exclusions -> None` to your plot command. Also, the documentation covers this [very example](http://wolfram.com/xid/0g7gylk19h6-ewkehp)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To plot $\lfloor x\rfloor$ you can use `DiscretePlot` at the integers with `ExtentSize` and `ExtentMarkers`:

```
DiscretePlot[Floor[x], {x, 0, 8}, ExtentSize -> Right, 
 ExtentMarkers -> {"Filled", "Empty"}, Filling -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work on v7, which explains why I haven't used these options before. :-/

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, the `Extent*` options were added in V8.

Answer (score 2):

From the help:

```
Plot[Floor[x], {x, 0, 10}, ExclusionsStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]