# Unexpected Behaviour at Plotting Floor with Plot

Tags: plotting

I wanted to plot a function involving `Floor`, here is my code:

```
epsilon = 0.1;
f[t_] = Floor[t/epsilon];
Plot[{f[t]}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

it gives me the following, which has smaller bars as `t` increases:
[image]

I know that I can plot Floor with `DiscretePlot`, as suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11102/plotting-a-floor-function-with-endpoints), but I would like to understand, why `Plot` cannot handle it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Related: [(29346)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29346/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify more `PlotPoints`

```
epsilon = 0.1;
f[t_] = Floor[t/epsilon];

Plot[{f[t]}, {t, 0, 5},
 PlotPoints -> 250,
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
epsilon = 0.5;
f[t_] = Floor[t/epsilon];

Plot[{f[t]}, {t, 0, 5},
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 PlotPoints -> 250,
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01],
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
epsilon = 0.5;
f[t_] = Floor[t/epsilon];

Plot[{f[t]}, {t, 0, 5},
 Filling -> Axis,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {Range[0, 5, 0.5], None}},
 GridLines -> {Range[0, 5, 0.5], Range[0, 10, 1]},
 PlotPoints -> 250,
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.001],
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, that solves the problem. but do you have an intuitive understanding why mathematica decides to make the bars smaller? So, why does it work better for small t as for large t?

Comment: @NicoDean I don't understand it either. With too few `PlotPoints` you just get unpredictable results. I don't even see a pattern "within" this unpredictability.

Comment: The bar length is determined by where the adaptive sampling for `Plot` selects the plot points. This is affected by the initial sampling points set by the option `PlotPoints`.